# regular expression pattern to accept one or multiple ip addresses?

Tags: java, regex

I am using below regular expression pattern

```
pattern="^(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))$|\s*
```

It will accept any one of the below ip address

```
1.1.2.3 or 192.122.134.1 or 198.23.45.56
```

But i want it should accept single as well as  ip addresses with comma separated as well like below

```
1.1.2.3,192.122.134.1,198.23.45.56
```

What changes i have to do in my regular expression?

Comment: Get rid of it completely and parse them properly would be my advice. Your life will be a lot easier in the long run.

Comment: Maybe you could split your String on the comma, then apply your regex on the tokens .

Comment: I agree with biziclop and Berger. At least: do not re-invent the wheel. Use your favorite search engine and check out the very complex regexes that you actually need to allow for all the various strange thingies that make up valid IP addresses.

Comment: @biziclop this input i am taking from a web application form ,without regex its very hard to validate

Comment: `(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\.(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))` remove the `^`  and `$` may work

Comment: @SubodhJoshi On the contrary, it is much simpler. You split the string along `,` characters, and you've got the individual IP addresses. You split them along `.`, and convert the parts into numbers, check that they give you a valid IP and you're done. As a bonus, you can also exclude IPs that are valid but may be unwanted, like `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: @Tim007 Its not working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It slowly becomes incomprehensible, but here you are:

> ^(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5])).(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5])).(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5])).(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))(,(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5])).(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5])).(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5])).(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5])))*$

What happens here is:

let's call your IP regexp **IP**:

> IP = ((\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5])).(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5])).(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5])).(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5])))

so we just have to repeat it with comma:

> ^IP(,IP)*$

Comment: Full marks for getting it right (probably), but if this came up in a code review, I'd kindly ask the author to think again. :)

Comment: @Maciej Dobrowolski   it will throw exception for single ip address 192.168.1.1

Comment: @SubodhJoshi give me... some time to debug it ;)

Comment: @MaciejDobrowolski So now u made changes?

Comment: @SubodhJoshi yes I did, you can see all changes by clicking `edited xxx xx ago`

Comment: We can repeat it by comma using `^((?(?!^),)IP)+$`, so you get `^((?(?!^),)(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5])).(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5])).(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5])).(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5])))+$`

Answer (score 1):

```
([1-9]\d?\d?(\.\d{1,3}){2}\.\d{1,3},?)+
```

A little over Reductionist perhaps, but that should handle it.
(you will need to trim out the commas from the matches though)
Edited to restrict matches to the range of 1.*.*.* -> 999.*.*.*

Comment: You mean, `0.999.543,7891.3.2.500` is a valid list of IP addresses?

Comment: it shouldn't match that pattern (run it through regex101.com now - it doesn't) but I agree about the issue with the 0, I'll update now.

Comment: @Minothor Please check this value `12.12.1.1,` Its not telling any issue with this number

Comment: I see what you mean, it is perhaps, a little over-reductionist, I'll refine it further, but I don't think I can feasibly refine it beyond the 0.0.0.0 -> 255.255.255.255 range, such validation would be best done in a more robust manner than pattern matching, as useful as it is.

Answer (score 0):

I´d rather not use regex as @biziclop did say.

You could just split the whole `String` and pass the ip adress to the [InetAddress.html#getByName](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getByName(java.lang.String)) method. from the documentation of the method:

> If a literal IP address is supplied, only the validity of the address format is checked

Basicly you could just pass the adress to this method, and the class itself would supply a validation of the adress. If the addres would be invalid you would run into a `java.net.UnknownHostException` which you would just have to catch. This way you would just have to create a regex that will successfully split all the ip-adresses

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {
    String adresses = "1.1.2.3.15,192.122.134.1,198.23.45.56";
    for(String s : adresses.split(",|\\sor\\s")) {
        try {
            InetAddress adress = Inet4Address.getByName(s);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid format for ip adress " + s);
        }
    }
    adresses = "1.1.2.3 or 192.122.134.1 or 198.23.45.56 ";
    for(String s : adresses.split(",|\\sor\\s")) {
        try {
            InetAddress adress = Inet4Address.getByName(s);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid format for ip adress " + s);
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
Invalid format for ip adress 1.1.2.3.15
```

Comment: The problem with `getByName()` is that it automatically resolves names, which may or may not be desirable.

Comment: @biziclop that´s true, but shouldn´t it be ok if OP supplies a list of ip adresses that should be validated?

Comment: @KevinEsche It cold be a good option but for me i have to call a java method to validate the input given by user that what i want to ignore.

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
^((2([0-4]\d|5[0-5])|1\d\d|[0]?[1-9]\d|[0]?[0]?\d)(\.(2([0-4]\d|5[0-5])|1\d\d|
[0]?[1-9]\d|[0]?[0]?\d)){3}([\s,](?!$)|$))*$
```

it will accept comma separated and space separated ips

Comment: @achabahe What about `192.168.1.1,12.12.1.1,`  its not invalidate it.

Comment: @MaciejDobrowolski  thanks i have made the adjustement fo it to work

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="country_code" pattern="^(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5])).(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5])).(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5])).(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))(,(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5])).(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5])).(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5])).(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5])))*$">
```

Use this input field in your HTML file